# MongoDB will not start after TLS configuration

Tags: mongodb, ssl

I am setting up a MongoDB server (I'm new to MongoDB). Everything works fine till I add the configuration for forcing TLS. I am using  a self signed certificate. MongoDB version is 4.2.5. Operating System is Windows Server 2016 Datacenter. I have enabled TLS in the registry for TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2. 
The below is my configuration file:
[image]

When I try to start the MongoDB service from Windows services, I get an error and the service won't start:
[image]

However, when I remove the below statements from the config file, it works:

```
net:
   tls:
      mode: requireTLS
      certificateSelector: thumbprint="‎45b3***************************4237"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anything in the log file?

Comment: @Joe The log file has no entries. I tried cleaning all from log file and retried

Comment: nothing in event viewer either?

Comment: I see two entries: #1: The MongoDB service failed to start due to the following error: 
The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion. #2: A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the MongoDB service to connect.

Comment: Can you start the mongod from the command line using the same config file?

Comment: Thanks. That gave me a clue as to what is going on. the double quotes were not required after the thumbprint.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551